# Why does my mesh disappear in Unity when I add armature and subsurface modifier together?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, blender

I'm making a rigged model by using Blender. And the rigged mesh seems okay when I run the project on Unity and android device as well if I didn't add "subdivision surface modifier" from Blender. But if I add "subdivision surface modifier", it normally runs and seems okay on Unity, but the mesh just disappears when I build the project and test it on my android device.

I've found out "subdivision surface modifier" affects the result in some way. My android device is not that old one(Android version : Oreo/API level 26), and I've tried adjust settings like minimum API level or target API level from Unity, but it didn't work at all.

I've been working on this almost three days already. Could anyone please help me out with this issue?

Comment: how do you import the blender model into unity? Do you export it properly into e.g. an `.fbx` file? Do you apply the subsurface modifier before that?

Comment: thank you for comment :) And yes, I exported it into .fbx file. And the issue always comes up whether I apply the subsurface modifier before exporting or not. I don't really get it why the subsurface modifier has to something to do with this issue.. Actually I don't even sure it's really the matter. I'm just guessing it because it's the only thing I figured out. I'd really appreciate it if you gave me any kind of clues about this issue.

Comment: Do you do any modification to the mesh in Unity?

Comment: check https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/temas/performance-optimization/optimizing-graphics-rendering-unity-games and https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ModelingOptimizedCharacters.html